# In XForms, with Orbeon, how to update an XML instance through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, orbeon, xforms

I want to perform some logic in JavaScript when users click on the span element and update current XML instance from jQuery:

(I have seen 2 similar questions online but they never got answered!)

XForms:

```
<xhtml:span class="buttonPlusOne" id="plusVat">+</xhtml:span>
<xf:output ref="instance('submitted_instance')/TotVATAmnt"></xf:output>
<xf:input id="changeVatTotal" ref="instance('submitted_instance')/TotVATAmnt"></xf:input>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('span.buttonPlusOne').on('click', function () {
    // do some logic and increment value for 0.01
    orbeonElId = $(this).siblings('#changeVatTotal').children('input').attr('id');
    // alert(orbeonElId) produces right id (changeVatTotal$xforms-input-1)
    // alert(newValue) produces 0.02 (for example)
    ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(orbeonElId, newValue);
});
```

I can see Orbeon posting data (Firebug), but the XML Instance does not get updated (input does not update the output - even though they share same "ref" attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you're mixing up the html element's id with the XForms id (`id` attribute) of the `xf:input` element.

The Orbeon documentation [shows an example](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-javascript-integration#TOC-Getting-and-Setting-Controls-Value-):  the id to use in the `ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue()` function call is the id of the (server-side) XForms element. So in your example it's `changeVatTotal`, and not the id of the (client-side) html input element `changeVatTotal$xforms-input-1`. This is why there's a request showing up in firebug with no effect on the XForms instance: the server-side XForms engine doesn't find a `xf:input` element with the id `changeVatTotal$xforms-input-1`, so it doesn't know what to do with that request.

This means, too, that you (usually) don't need to compute the id of the target element, instead you can just use the "plain" XForms id attribute value of the xf:input.

**Alternatively:**

Is it possible to handle the "plus" button completely in XForms? You could use a [`xforms:trigger` control](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#ui-trigger) and include a [`xforms:setvalue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#action-setvalue) action on the `DOMActivate` event:

```xml
<xf:trigger>
    <xf:label>+</xf:label>
    <xf:setvalue
        ev:event="DOMActivate"
        ref="instance('submitted_instance')/TotVATAmnt"
        value="0.01 + instance('submitted_instance')/TotVATAmnt" />
    <.... more actions ...>
</xf:trigger>
```

I think this solution would be more stable than doing some of the work client-side and some server-side.

Comment: Hi, thanks, tried with the #changeVatTotal,
same issue again,
Seems like the input does not change the output (which is unusual behaviour - they share same "ref" attr.).
Do you think that it might have anything to do with JQuery?
Thanks for trying to help, really frustrating, spent a good few ours already on it... !

Comment: In fact i may be connected with JQuery - you could test this by issueing a ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue() to an xf:input element on the xforms-ready event, for example, that doesn't depend on JQuery. BTW: do you try to update the same input element that triggers the setvalue? Does it change anything if you use any other input element (even a hidden one) as setvalue() target?

Comment: **1.** I am pressing a **"+"** button (that first xhtml span) to add 0.01 to the input (that should update output as they have same "ref") - I guess ;)
**2.** If I used a different id to update in JQuery:
`ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue('invoiceDate', currValue);`
- it works and that #invoiceDate input:text gets a new value.
Does that answers your questions?

Comment: Ok - so JQuery isn't the cuplrit, and setvalue() works in general. To figure out wh it doesn't work with #changeVatTotal, i fear that more information about the XForm is required. Could you add relevant parts of the xforms instance definition to your question? What do the [Orbeon logs](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging) tell about the setvalue request?

Comment: Ok, ok, mystery solved! 3.5 conclusions:
**1.** Make sure that there is no calculations in the X-Forms model that automatically change value of an element you are trying to update manually from JS.
**2.** When using Orbeon API to manually update your current XML Instance - go rather for id of X-Forms than for the DOM id of your input.
**3.** It turned out that the issues above - when eliminated - solved the problem (still gotta somehow bring back my calculations but at least know what was causing the headache!)
**4.** And everybody blamed poor jQ Sizzle ;)
THANKS FOR HELP!

Comment: @tohuwawohu Thank you for the answer. I updated your answer above to remove the paragraph you had under the first "EDIT": the id to use in `setValue` is really the id you have on the `<xf:input>`, not the id on the HTML `<input>` generated by Orbeon Forms, as you were saying earlier. If you found something that contradicts what I just said in the documentation, please let me know, and I'll update the documentation.

Comment: @avernet: i was referring to the following explanation: "_The first parameter (myControl in the above example) can either be: The id of the control (a string); The **element in the DOM** that has this id_." In the second case, i thought that the DOM was the browser DOM, so the element would be the client-side HTML element.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I ended up actually doing it through X-Forms as you adviced (with the Trigger), working like a Charm ;) I am just much more familiar with JS than X-Forms, but the conclusion is (as far as my experience so far is telling me) : ALWAYS use X-Forms to achieve your goal, and only if you can't - fall back on the custom Client Side code. Especially if the X-Forms is re-calculating the fields!
Thanks again!!

Comment: @alchemication happy to hear this :-)